# Javascript Regular Expression Remove Spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

So i'm writing a tiny little plugin for JQuery to remove spaces from a string. [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ge59E/)

```
(function($) {
    $.stripSpaces = function(str) {
        var reg = new RegExp("[ ]+","g");
        return str.replace(reg,"");
    }
})(jQuery);
```

my regular expression is currently `[ ]+` to collect all spaces. 
This works.. however It doesn't leave a good taste in my mouth.. 
I also tried `[\s]+` and `[\W]+` but neither worked..

There has to be a better (more concise) way of searching for only spaces.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

I would recommend you use the literal notation, and the `\s` character class:

```
//..
return str.replace(/\s/g, '');
//..
```

There's a difference between using the character class `\s` and just `' '`,  this will match a lot more white-space characters, for example `'\t\r\n'` etc.., looking for `' '` will replace only the ASCII 32 blank space.

The `RegExp` constructor is useful when you want to *build* a dynamic pattern, in this case you don't need it.

Moreover, as you said, `"[\s]+"` didn't work with the `RegExp` constructor, that's because you are passing a string, and you should "double escape" the back-slashes, otherwise they will be interpreted as character escapes inside the string (e.g.: `"\s" === "s"` (unknown escape)).

Comment: I read somewhere that `\s+` is faster, as it matches longer, thus might reduce the number of internal replace.

Answer (score 14):

```
"foo is bar".replace(/ /g, '')
```

Answer (score 5):

**In production and works across line breaks**

This is used in several apps to clean user-generated content removing extra spacing/returns etc but retains the meaning of spaces.

```
text.replace(/[\n\r\s\t]+/g, ' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

This works just as well: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ge59E/3/

```
var reg = new RegExp(" ","g"); //<< just look for a space.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str.replace(/\s/g,'')
```

Works for me.

`jQuery.trim` has the following hack for IE, although I'm not sure what versions it affects:

```
// Check if a string has a non-whitespace character in it
rnotwhite = /\S/

// IE doesn't match non-breaking spaces with \s
if ( rnotwhite.test( "\xA0" ) ) {
    trimLeft = /^[\s\xA0]+/;
    trimRight = /[\s\xA0]+$/;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove all spaces in string

```
// Remove only spaces
`
Text with spaces 1 1     1     1 
and some
breaklines

`.replace(/ /g,'');
"
Textwithspaces1111
andsome
breaklines

"

// Remove spaces and breaklines
`
Text with spaces 1 1     1     1
and some
breaklines

`.replace(/\s/g,'');
"Textwithspaces1111andsomebreaklines"
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of them should work:

```js
text.replace(/ +/g,' ')
```

Or:

```
text.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ')
```

```js
const text = "eat healthy     and  drink  gallon of  water."


text.replace(/ +/g,' ')
// eat healthy and drink gallon of water.

text.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ')
// eat healthy and drink gallon of water.
```