# Stripping spaces with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to remove one or more space characters using regular expression.

Input:

```
hello                        world
```

Desired Output:

```
helloworld
```

Comment: I'm not a regexp expert so i won't be able to provide code but this could be done easily by replacing strings containing a variable number of spaces by an empty string using a regexp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Regular Expression Remove Spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151159/javascript-regular-expression-remove-spaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a RegExp [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on the string

```
'hello                        world'.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // "helloworld"
```

`\s` means *whitespace*
`+` means "one or more"
`g` means "global", as in "match multiple times"

Comment: Yeah, more here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151159/javascript-regular-expression-remove-spaces

Comment: I don't see how you're getting that output from the code I posted. I cannot reproduce what you say.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code it should be producing

```
helloworl
```

and not `hello`

The `d` would be chopped off because of the `-1` in the for loop comparison. It should not be there. Your code running fine with the `-1` removed: http://jsfiddle.net/3Hjq5/

But why are you looping? A simple regular expression can do it.

```
function removeSpaces(str) {
    return str.replace(/\s+/g,"");
}
```

Running example of reg expression: http://jsfiddle.net/3Hjq5/1/

Comment: @usandfriends Did you actually look at your browser's console? That's where you'll see "helloworld"

Comment: You are developing in JavaScript and you do not know what the JavaScript console is? Do some research on it.