# how to curtail leading and trailing white spaces

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "    abcd    ";

if(str.match(/\ /)) { 
    document.writeln("String Empty");
} else {
    document.writeln("Length :  ");
    document.writeln(str.length);
}
```

The above code always returns an empty string although it has characters in between.

I need to chop the leading and trailing white spaces.

Comment: Taken from another [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151159/javascript-regular-expression-remove-spaces):

`str.replace(/\s/g, '');`

Answer (score 1):

```
// Remove leading and trailing whitespace
// Requires jQuery
var str = " a b    c d e f g ";
var newStr = $.trim(str);
// "a b c d e f g"

// Remove leading and trailing whitespace
// JavaScript RegEx
var str = "   a b    c d e f g ";
var newStr = str.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,'');
// "a b c d e f g"

// Remove all whitespace
// JavaScript RegEx
var str = " a b    c d e   f g   ";
var newStr = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
// "abcdefg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trim and check the length:

```
if (!str.trim().length) { 
  document.writeln("String Empty");
}
else {
 document.writeln("Length : ");
 document.writeln(str.trim().length);
}
```