# AJAX - PHP responseText won't return anything

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My AJAX register script isn't working because of the `responseText()` function I have, in my PHP part I echo 0 to 12(and 100) depending on the if condition.

And if eg: the users username isn't valid it needs to give an error, it needs to give echo 2 and responseText then needs to give the error.

But it won't, It will give me nothing(no var_dump, no console bug, no php_error_log, and no Apache error log).

**My Jquery/AJAX part:**

```
    if(username.val() != '' && password.val() != '' && password2.val() != '' && email.val() != '' && terms.val != '')
    {
        var UrlToPass = 'action=aanmelden&username='+username.val()+'&password='+password.val()+'&password2='+password2.val()+'&email='+email.val()+'&av='+terms.val();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data : UrlToPass,
            url  : '/outgame/register.php',
            success : function(responseText)
            {
                if(responseText == 0)
                {
                  $.notify('U hebt geen gebruikersnaam opgegeven!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 1)
                {
                  $.notify('Uw gebruikersnaam moet meer dan 3 en minder dan 16 karakters bevatten!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 2)
                {
                  $.notify('Uw gebruikersnaam bevat ongeldige tekens!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 3)
                {
                  $.notify('U hebt geen wachtwoord opgegeven!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 4)
                {
                  $.notify('Uw wachtwoord moet meer dan 6 en minder dan 16 karakters bevatten!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 5)
                {
                  $.notify('U hebt geen tweede wachtwoord opgegeven!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 6)
                {
                  $.notify('De wachtwoorden komen niet met elkaar overeen!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 7)
                {
                  $.notify('U hebt geen mail adres opgegeven!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 8)
                {
                  $.notify('Uw mail adres is niet geldig!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 9)
                {
                  $.notify('Uw gebruikersnaam is al ingebruik!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 10)
                {
                  $.notify('Er is al een account aagemaakt met dit email adres!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 11)
                {
                  $.notify('U hebt onze AV niet geaccepteerd!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 12)
                {
                  $.notify('Uw invoer voor onze AV is ongeldig!', 'error');
                }
                else if(responseText == 100)
                {
                  $.notify('U bent succesvol geregistreerd', 'success');
                }
                else
                {
                  alert('error!');
                }
            }

        });
    }

    return false;
    })
});
```

(Sorry the code is messy)

**My PHP part:**

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'aanmelden')
{
    $stringUsername   = trim($_POST['username']);
    $stringPassword   = trim($_POST['password']);
    $stringPassword2  = trim($_POST['password2']);
    $stringEmail      = trim($_POST['email']);
    $stringTerms      = trim($_POST['av']);
    $bolean           = false;
    $stringsmallUser  = strtolower($stringUsername);

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $stringsmallUser);
    $stmt->execute();
    $intMatchu = $stmt->num_rows();
    $stmt->close();

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $stringEmail);
    $stmt->execute();
    $intMatche = $stmt->num_rows();
    $stmt->close();

    if(empty($stringUsername))
    {
        echo 0;
        $bolean = true;
    }
    elseif(strlen($stringUsername) < 3 || strlen($stringUsername) > 16)
    {
        echo 1;
        $bolean = true;
    }
    elseif(!ctype_alnum($stringUsername))
    {
        echo 2;
        $bolean = true;
    }

    if(empty($stringPassword))
    {
        echo 3;
        $bolean = true;
    }
    elseif(strlen($stringPassword) < 6 || strlen($stringPassword) > 16)
    {
        echo 4;
        $bolean = true;
    }

    if(empty($stringPassword2))
    {
        echo 5;
        $bolean = true;
    }
    elseif($stringPassword != $stringPassword2)
    {
        echo 6;
        $bolean = true;
    }

    if(empty($stringEmail))
    {
        echo 7;
        $bolean = true;
    }
    elseif(!filter_var($stringEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        echo 8;
        $bolean = true;
    }

    if($intMatchu != 0)
    {
        echo 9;
        $bolean = true;
    }
    elseif($intMatchu != 0)
    {
        echo 10;
        $bolean = true;
    }

    if(empty($stringTerms))
    {
        echo 11;
        $bolean = true;
    }
    elseif($stringTerms == 'avok')
    {
        echo 12;
        $bolean = true;
    }

    if($bolean == false)
    {
        echo 100;
    }
}

else
{
    exit();
}
```

(The queries work, I've put them in PHPmyAdmin and they work.)

Thank you in advance! :-) English isn't also my mother tongue so I'm sorry for my grammar mistakes.

Comment: Include your code in the question; link rot.

Comment: Have you looked that values are returned in your network tab?

Comment: I have a feeling that your php `echo`'s are sending some white space with them, hence why your jquery/javascript `if` conditions to check the number aren't working. Look at [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)

Comment: Quick tip: Learn about `switch`.

Comment: Daedalus: I've edited my post, thank you. Darren: But if I'm echoën integers there can't be white space or am I wrong? Niet The Dark Absol: I was working with the switch case method, it only didn't work as if now that why I did switch from method

Comment: @RezaMO Oh trust me, just throw a `console.log(responseText);` into your `success` function there and copy it, almost certainly there will be white space.

Comment: @Darren Indeed I'm getting white space, the odd thing is, the return is this: "14812 ". But how can I remove the white space? I have tried the trim jquery function. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RezaMO Whitespace after the closing php tag would do it.

Comment: @RezaMO or with the echo, but as you see, multiple coditions are being met... you'll need to refactor your code to only return one at a time or an array of the issues.

Comment: Deadalus, I've checked all closing PHP tags but none of them have white space after it... :-( Darren, can you give an example how to use the trim function in my way?

Comment: It would be better to send json and check like that.

Comment: I've tried to fix it by removing all closing php tags, but also no result...

Comment: @RezaMO It doesn't alert me if you don't use the @.

Comment: @RezaMO Well, the way you talk it sounds like you have multiple closing tags.  But without seeing the actual code there, anything I put here is just speculation.  I can however say this: Its better to treat the cause than the symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

There is a far simpler way to achieve what you're trying to do here.
Instead of `echo`'ing out all of these values, you should look into adding them to an array. The below is a pseudo example to explain how you'd do it.

```
$errors = array();
if(CONDITION MAKES ERROR) {
    $errors[] = 1;
} elseif(OTHER CONDITION MAKES ERROR) {
    $errors[] = 2;
}....etc
```

Now after you've run all of those `if` conditions, you can simply add this to the end of that php script:

```
echo json_encode($errors);
```

Which would ([<sup>*Based on your comment*</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194260/ajax-php-responsetext-wont-return-anything#comment39234181_25194260)) return a `json` array that looks like this:

```
[1,4,8,2]
```

Allowing you to loop through the `responseText` and echo messages for each of the errors.

---

Alternatively, you could just `$.trim()`, something like this:

```
$.trim(responseText);
```

[**`or look at this answer to use regex (via the replace() method) instead.`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7151225/2518525)

Comment: I'm getting this back: "[1,4,6,8,12] ". Still with white space, I've tried to look-up a way to get response trough array. But I don't know how to work with array and responseText. Thank you very much for helping ! :-)