# Parsing JSON object with space in key value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to execute node js code using powershell. Sending JSON object as command line argument to nodejs program to process.

```
//Java Script Code
let command = JSON.parse(process.argv[2].split('\\').join('') || '{}');
console.log(JSON.stringify(command));
console.log(command.bonding_options);
```

Here is the PowerShell Command:

```
C:\nodejs\node Parse.js '"{\"bonding_options\":\"mode=802.3ad miimon=100 xmit_hash_policy=layer3+4\"}"'
```

If you see closely, input argument has space e.g "mode=802.3ad miimon". Space between '3ad miimon'
Original input has spaces which we cannot avoid. If I send input with space value, I get below Error:

```
{"bonding_options":"mode=802.3ad


SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kp250041\Desktop\Myfiles\Parse.js:3:20)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

If white spaces are removed, it worked:

```
{ bonding_options: 'mode=802.3admiimon=100xmit_hash_policy=layer3+4' }
mode=802.3admiimon=100xmit_hash_policy=layer3+4
```

Please advise, how to handle white spaces in scenario like this.
Thanks for help in advance.

Thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you cannot modify the argument, here is a hacky solution:

```
process.argv.splice(0,2)
let command = JSON.parse(process.argv.join(" ").split('\\').join('') || '{}');
console.log(JSON.stringify(command));
var objarr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(command));
console.log(command.bonding_options);
```

Comment: This worked !! As we cannot control input/arguments so this trick is very useful. Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to replace all instances of the space character within a string

string.replace(/\s/g, '')

```js
var inputString = "This is a test string"
console.log(inputString.replace(/\s/g, ''))
```

See this article for an in-depth explanation: [Javascript Regular Expression Remove Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151159/javascript-regular-expression-remove-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

The code you are sending in is currently to much escaped :) you send your command with both single quotes & doubles quotes at both the beginning and the end of the string. But the argument will already be a string, so no need for the double quotes at all

So, I think your command to nodejs should be:

C:\nodejs\node Parse.js '{"bonding_options":"mode=802.3ad miimon=100 xmit_hash_policy=layer3+4"}'

and you don't have to remove the `\` as you don't have any at that time (the code is surrounded with single ' therefor, no need to escape the double ones

```js
function parseArgs( args, index = 2 ) {
  return JSON.parse(args[index] || '{}').bonding_options;
}

console.log( parseArgs( ['{\"bonding_options\":\"mode=802.3ad miimon=100 xmit_hash_policy=layer3+4\"}'], 0 ) );

console.log( parseArgs( ['{"bonding_options":"mode=802.3ad miimon=100 xmit_hash_policy=layer3+4"}'], 0 ) );
```