# How to remove whitespace chunks ending with a newline from string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a trouble with removing all spaces from a string.

```
Stehn        
Stehn        
Simchart
Simchart
Stehn        
Stehn        
Stehn        
Stehn        
Stehn
```

This is the string, which has new lines, spaces, and so on.

```
string.replace(/[\r\n]+/gm, ', ')
```

Doing this, only returns me

`Stehn        , Stehn        , Simchart, Simchart, Stehn        , Stehn        , Orion Reederei GmbH & Co KG, Orion Reederei GmbH & Co KG, Stehn        , Stehn        , Stehn        , Arrow Shipping Germany, "`

But I would like to get a normalized and sanitized string with commas.

```
string.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ',').split(',').map(s => s.trim()).join(', ')
```

This code, however, resolves my problem, but I don't like this solution as I have thousands inside my table.

Comment: `\s` matches any whitespace character - is that what you need?

Comment: Its \s , but it doesn't help me

Comment: \s matches \r,\n and \s, i.e whitespaces. So i'd prefer if you gave a literal whitespace if that's what you are targeting

Comment: Why doesn't `\s` help? You want *all* whitespace to be replaced so it seems like the logical choice. If it doesn't work, then there is something that isn't present in the question.

Comment: Yes I know, We can replace it, but I tried different ways. And also a problem is that I have a word like `Orion Reederei GmbH & Co KG` and it has spaces but not replaceable.

Comment: Then please add it in the question. It's not obvious that "all kind of spaces" has restrictions.

Comment: This is what you are looking for `.replace(/\s+/g, ', ')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Regular Expression Remove Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151159/javascript-regular-expression-remove-spaces)

Comment: When you give an example you should *always* show the desired result, not just an undesired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just try replacing all whitespace along with an immediately following CR?LF with just a single comma and space.

```js
var input = "Stehn        \nStehn        \nSimchart\nSimchart\nStehn       \nStehn        \nStehn        \nStehn        \nStehn ";
var output = input.replace(/\s*?\r?\n/g, ", ");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan If that works, use a more efficient `/[^\S\n]*\n/g`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single pattern, and in the replacement use a comma and a single space.

```
[^\S\r\n]*[\r\n]+
```

- `[^\S\r\n]*` [Negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), match 0+ times a whitespace char except newlines
- `[\r\n]+` Match 1+ newlines (for a single newline, use `\r?\n`)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7jPIjI/1)

```js
    const regex = /[^\S\r\n]*[\r\n]+/g;
    const str = `Stehn        
Stehn        
Simchart
Simchart
Stehn        
Stehn        
Stehn        
Stehn        
Stehn  `;
    const result = str.replace(regex, `, `);
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: What's better in this case, I am confused. @TimBiegeleisen solution is also good and short. Why the one could be better?

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan Both solutions work. The difference is in that `\s` can also match `\r` and `\n` Making it lazy will involve backtracking to expand the match for \s by one item until it matches a newline.
Using `[^\S\r\n]` excludes matching newlines.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is:

```
let s = "a     b     c         d    e   \nf    g  h\n\ni";
```

Then you can strip with:

```
s.split(/\s+/)
```

And combine:

```
s.split(/\s+/).join(',');
```

If instead it's a newline thing and you want to trim, then why not just split? Easier than replacing, splitting, trimming, and rejoining:

```
s.split(/\r?\n|\r/).map(s => s.trim()).join(', ')
```

Comment: Seems `s.split(/\r?\n|\r/).map(s => s.trim()).join(', ')` is the only solution for this case . I will mark it as accepted, if there is not better solution.

Comment: There is a better solution which doesn't require using `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to substitute `whitespace` with `,` you must write a regex that matches whitespaces

**Regex:** `/\b\s+\b/gm`

> **g:** global mode
>
> **m:** multiline mode

Now at this point your regex should match all the spaces. Now all you have to do is replace them with `,`

*Note that I am using word boundaries here since you do not want `,` at the end of your last string.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function removeAllBlankSpaces(str) {
   return str.split('').filter(s => s != ' ').join('');
}

console.log(removeAllBlankSpaces('str ing');
```